# Javascript- this.increment does not increment when method calls itself

Tags: javascript

```
var CHECK_ITERATIONS = 5;

function NewCheckEvent(device, account, eventId, url) {
    this.iteration = 0;
    this.status = "checking";
    this.device = device;
    this.url = url;
}   

NewCheckEvent.prototype.runCheckLoop = function() {
    if (this.iteration < CHECK_ITERATIONS) {
         this.iteration = this.iteration++;
         console.log('iteration ' + this.iteration);
          setTimeout(function (){
              this.runCheckLoop();
          }.bind(this), 1000);
    }
}


var bob = new NewCheckEvent(14245, 92136, "9f2b2d3f-45d4-a82f-b12e082b1164", "dddd");
console.log(bob);
bob.runCheckLoop();
```

---

```
one@localhost ~ $ node try.js 
{ iteration: 0, status: 'checking', device: 14245, url: 'dddd' }
iteration 0
iteration 0
iteration 0
```

How come this.iteration does not increment when `runCheckLoop` call's itself in the setTimeout? How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: Besides the correct advice in the answers, another problem is that the value of `this` in the timeout handler will not be the same as it is in the "runCheckLoop" context.

Comment: Please explain... I thought it would because of .bind(this)

Comment: DOH!  missed that. Yes, that should be fine then!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
this.iteration = this.iteration++;
```

`this.iteration++` increments the property, but it then returns the original value. The assignment to the left sets it back to the original value. Maybe you wanted just

```
this.iteration++;
```

Comment: Or `this.iteration = ++this.iteration;`

Answer (score 3):

The problem in line

```
this.iteration = this.iteration++;
```

Here you actually say: set this.iteration = this.iteration and then increment; therefore you assigning old value back. It should be just

```
this.iteration++;
```

instead.